# DATEADD MINUTES Between Range MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, date-range, dateadd, minute

I am having some difficulty in trying to figure out something, lets say I have a date and time;

And I want to add 180 minutes to it so;

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,180,'2018-05-24 15:00')
```

This would give me answer of "2018-05-24 18:00" but I want to do it in a range so ADD the minutes if you are between 09:00 - 17:00 so something like this;

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTES,180,'2018-05-24 15:00') WHERE '2018-05-24 15:00' BETWEEN '2018-05-24 09:00' AND '2018-05-24 17:00'
```

So the answer to this would be "2018-05-25 10:00"

Comment: 15 is between 9-17. so output should be 18:00, right?

Comment: @Sahi - OP means that if you reach 17:00, then you should count the remaining time left to add on from 09:00 the following day

Comment: I need it to roll onto the next day for the minutes, the output is correct in 18:00 but I need it to roll over that extra hour onto the next day because it is not it working hours.

Comment: u mean, the DateTime after the DateADD operation should be comapred in 9-17 range.?

Comment: OK then what if I want to add 1167 minutes to a start time but only utilise the counting between 09:00-17:00.. I need to make an end time to be within the working hours. I cant have it count between early hours of the morning when they are not a work.

Comment: Lets try and simplify it; lets speak in hours, start day is Monday 09:00 and I need to utilise 20 Hours. The working hours are 09:00 - 17:00 which is 8 hours a day so I want the end time to be Wednesday 13:00.

Comment: @Kiel I know you already marked your solution, but if you still see inconsistent results, you are free to try my solution.

Comment: Let me look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hard, but this should work for all your cases. This solution works for any amount of (positive) minutes and result will always be inside the parametrized hours, adding the corresponding amount of days.

```
DECLARE @RangeHourStart INT = 9
DECLARE @RangeHourEnd INT = 17

DECLARE @MinutesToAdd INT = 120

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2018-05-24 15:00'

SELECT
    FinalDate = CASE 
        WHEN -- When final hour exceeds the range hour
            DATEPART(HOUR, @Date) * 60 + 
            DATEPART(MINUTE, @Date) +
            @MinutesToAdd % ((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60) > @RangeHourEnd * 60 

        THEN
            DATEADD(HOUR, -1 * (@RangeHourStart - 1), 
                DATEADD(DAY, 1, 
                    DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd % ((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60), 
                        DATEADD(
                            DAY,
                            @MinutesToAdd / ((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60),
                            @Date)))) 

        ELSE
            DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd % ((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60), 
                DATEADD(
                    DAY,
                    @MinutesToAdd / ((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60),
                    @Date))
        END
```

I made it so you don't need to hard-code any value.

Comment: This would be mint, if I could say dont work on saturday and sunday and  say on friday 16:00 is the finishing time. It does work great though and I have added 1255 minutes to it which lands me on sunday. I need to think about modding this to my needs.

Comment: How would you add 09:30 or 16:30 to your code, as its marked as integer 9 and 17.

Comment: @Kiel in that case change them so they are minutes and not hours. Hour 09:30 would be 9.5 * 60 minutes and 16:30 would be 16.5 * 60. Will have to remove all factors 60 that are multiplying the range hour variables (change `((@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart) * 60)` for `(@RangeHourEnd - @RangeHourStart)`. You might have to tweak a few other things also unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look particularly pretty, however...

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Times (DateNTime datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO Times
VALUES ('20180520 10:00:00'),
       ('20180520 15:20:00'),
       ('20180521 09:32:00'),
       ('20180521 14:17:00'),
       ('20180522 16:54:00'),
       ('20180523 12:46:00'),
       ('20180524 15:32:00');
GO


SELECT *
FROM Times;
GO

SELECT T.DateNTime,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(time,T.DateNTime) <= '14:00' THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 180,T.DateNTime)
            ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE,T.DateNTime,DATEADD(HOUR,17,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, T.DateNTime),0))), DATEADD(HOUR,9,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, T.DateNTime) + 1,0))) END
FROM Times T;

GO

DROP TABLE Times;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
DECLARE @input DATETIME='2018-05-24 15:00'
    DECLARE @min INT=180

    SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(MINUTE,@min,@input)>DATEADD(HOUR, 17,DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day,0, @input), 0)) 
        THEN  DATEADD(MINUTE,
                        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                                DATEADD(HOUR, 17,
                                    DATEADD(Day, 
                                        DATEDIFF(Day,0, @input),
                                    0)
                                ),
                                DATEADD(MINUTE,@min,@input)), 
                                    DATEADD(Hour,9,
                                        DATEADD(Day,1,
                                            DateAdd(Day, 
                                                Datediff(Day,0, @input),
                                                0)
                                        )
                                    )
                                )

        ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE,@min,@input)
        END
```

Comment: Try setting @min to 900, result is 22:00.

Comment: This only works if it was 1 day ahead as soon as you go 2 days it messes up. Try adding 1180 minutes you early hours of morning.